# Database Design - How to store and use flexible custom user events?

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, tracking

I am trying to wrap my head around how to design a database (in my case postgresql) to store flexible and custom events. The idea is not to have to create different rows for each new event I want to track.

Here is a first idea of how it could be:

[image]

The problem here is that it then becomes quite hard to analyse with other tools (e.g. excel or Tableau) as now the traditional name of the row is contained as a value.

Given that data before, here is a structure that could be better for analysis as the row names are the specific events:

[image]

To summarise my question: how can I go about storing events with variable `key` and different types of `value` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the original key/value design.

The structure of your table has no influence on the presentation of data, for example if you export them for use with a spreadsheet. When exporting data, you can always use a query like

```
SELECT timestamp, user_id,
       jsonb_object_agg(key, values)
FROM (SELECT timestamp, user_id, key
             jsonb_agg(value) AS values
      GROUP BY timestamp, user_id, key) AS q
GROUP BY timestamp, user_id;
```

Comment: I gave a try to the solution but the resulting table has the results in a JSON format. Is there any way to get the data still in separate columns?

Comment: I don't know of any. I would do that in client code.